# To which phase of database design is Database Denormalization formally placed

Tags: database-design

Formally speaking, to what stage of the database design process does database denormalization belong--logical design? or physical design? The process of joining relations into one, adding redundant attributes, etc seems like a logical design. However, denormalization seems to be done after the physical design of the db, which seems to make it fall under physical design. Which leads me to the question, where does denormalization belong?

Comment: A few questions arise.
1. In principle, de-normalize is OLAP and should not be used for OLTP.
2. What is the reason for de-normalization? (It may be used for limited purposes in OLTP.)
3. According to my studies, Normalization is required when designing a DW. Do you want to use a data warehouse?
4. what is you DBMS ?

Answer (score 1):

DB design is rather a cyclic process than linear so we can come back to the logical design after the physical phase again and again.